# Cant use RegExp with playwright-javascript Filter

Tags: javascript, playwright

I would like to use getByRole and Filter to click on a specific button. I dont know exactly the name of the button.

It can have uppercases and 0 or 1 spaces between each character (for example we can consider that I am trying to find the button with the name: "MAtch ST r") and I can only rely on the variable: regExStr = "matchstr".

The regEx seems correct in the piece of code shown below, according to regex101 website. But playwright cant find the button anyway. any help ?

````
       regExStr = "matchstr"
       await page
      .getByRole("button")
      .filter({ hasText: `/${regExStr.split("").join("\\s?")}.../i` })
      .click();```
````

Comment: Please share a complete, runnable [mcve] with the website you're automating. If the name is so variable, maybe select it using some other means. Thanks.

Comment: template literal is resolved as string. So propably you need new RegExp(), but that template needs some adjustments also

Comment: @ggorlen I have created the code below I am using the string ASkquestion to try to find Ask Question button on this page:`
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test(`Go to Table View: ${tableName}`, async ({ page }) => {
await page.goto(`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78088790/cant-use-regexp-with-playwright-javascript-filter?noredirect=1#comment137668791_78088790`);

       regExStr = "ASkquestion"
       await page
      .getByRole("button")
      .filter({ hasText: `/${regExStr.split("").join("\\s?")}.../i` })
      .click();```

Comment: Please [edit] the post. This isn't readable. `split("").join("\\s?")` is a very strange regex to want to build, and not necessary for scraping anything on Stack Overflow, or any website I've ever seen. Why are you doing that at all? By "that", I mean making it so you can match text like `A s k Q u e s t i o n`? Please take a step back and share the actual page and desired result, so we can avoid an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).